# PHP typecasting null or int

Tags: php, typecasting-operator

I want to let a variable be an int unless the variable is null.
This is the way I fixed it atm but there's got to be a better solution.

```
if ($answer == null) {
      $all_questions[] = array (
        'object_id'     => (int) $stored_question->getObjectId(),
        'question_code' => $stored_question->getQuestionCode(),
        'answer'        => $stored_question->getAnswer()
      );
    }
    else{
      $all_questions[] = array (
        'object_id'     => (int) $stored_question->getObjectId(),
        'question_code' => $stored_question->getQuestionCode(),
        'answer'        => (int) $stored_question->getAnswer()
      );
```

At least I hope there is because this seems redundant.

Comment: `is_null($x)?$x:intval($x)`, but as I see in your case `getAnswer` returns an integer as string or null you shoud cast the return value there

Comment: Note that the code in the question *does not do* what Wouter asks for [*be an int unless the variable is null*], for any `$answer` that PHP considers `false`. Because in PHP, ***null == false***. Before code above, do any of these: `$answer = 0;` or `$answer="0";` or `$answer=0.0;` or `$answer=false;`. None of those are "null", yet they are all `== null`. To test for null, use `=== null`, not `== null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$all_questions[] = [
    'object_id'     => (int) $stored_question->getObjectId(),
    'question_code' => $stored_question->getQuestionCode(),
    'answer'        => empty($answer)? $stored_question->getAnswer(): intval($stored_question->getAnswer())
];
```

Comment: Don't use `empty`. That returns true for entities that might surprise you, such as the string `"0.0"`. So this answer does not meet requirements; it will return values other than ints or null. As [shivani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37454370/199364) shows, if you want to test for null, *then test for null*. `is_null` or `=== null` are two ways to do so.

Answer (score 4):

First Declare Common think which you want from both  codition

```
$all_questions[] = array (
        'object_id'     => (int) $stored_question->getObjectId(),
        'question_code' => $stored_question->getQuestionCode(),
      );
```

Which will depend on certain condition

```
$all_questions['answer'] = (is_null($answer)) ? 
  $stored_question->getAnswer() : (int) $stored_question->getAnswer() :
```

Comment: Upvoted. Perfectly matches the question. FWIW, for *most people* writing code like this, `$answer` is the value to be returned, won't need to call `getAnswer()` again. In that case,  the code simplifies to `... = is_null($answer) ? null : (int)$answer;`.  OPTION: It isn't necessary to separate out the final property assignment; that can be done as part of the array initialization. I typicallly do the "fix up" first:  `if (!is_null($answer)) $answer = (int)$answer; $all_questions[] = array ( 'object_id' => ..., 'answer' => $answer );`